Can we make an aptitude search case-sensitive?
In a script:
aptitude search "?description($1)"
... can that be made case-sensitive?

Related: Aptitude regex engine

No mention of case in there.

The documentation quoted there says “Most textual searches (for package names, descriptions, etc) are performed using case-insensitive regular expressions.”

Right, which is why I'm asking if case-sensitive is possible and if so, how it might be done.  I already know that case-insensitive is normal.

aptitude uses the POSIX regcomp() / regexec() API from the system's C library to do regexp matching and calls regcomp() with the REG_ICASE | REG_EXTENDED flags, so you get mostly the same as grep -iE¹, and there's no builtin support for turning case-insensitivity off.
Now, if you're willing to spend a bit of effort, there are still things you could do. It's all free and opensource software after all so there is never any limit in what you can do.
For instance, you could intercept the regcomp() libc function invocations via a LD_PRELOAD trick to remove that REG_ICASE flag:
$ cat case-sensitive.c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <regex.h>

int regcomp (regex_t *_Restrict_ __preg,
             const char *_Restrict_ __pattern,
             int __cflags)
{
  static int (*orig) (regex_t *_Restrict_ __preg,
                      const char *_Restrict_ __pattern,
                      int __cflags) = 0;
  if (!orig)
    orig = (int (*) (regex_t *_Restrict_ __preg,
                     const char *_Restrict_ __pattern,
                     int __cflags)) dlsym (RTLD_NEXT, "regcomp");
  return (*orig)(__preg, __pattern, __cflags & ~REG_ICASE);
}

$ gcc -fPIC -shared -o case-sensitive.so case-sensitive.c

Then you can see its effect for instance by searching for the zsh package whose description contains Zsh is a UNIX command interpreter:
$ apt-cache show zsh
Package: zsh
[...]
Description-en_GB: shell with lots of features
 Zsh is a UNIX command interpreter (shell) usable as an interactive login
[...]

$ aptitude search -F %p '~n "^zsh$" ~d "Zsh .* unix"'
zsh
zsh:i386
$ LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/case-sensitive.so aptitude search -F %p '~n "^zsh$" ~d "Zsh .* unix"'
$ LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/case-sensitive.so aptitude search -F %p '~n "^zsh$" ~d "Zsh .* UNIX"'
zsh
zsh:i386

That case-insensive.so can be used for anything that uses the libc's regcomp()/regexec() API. You can tell if one does for a particular regexp matching with a debugger or ltrace for instance.
With int regcomp(addr, string, bitvec(int)); added to ~/.ltrace.conf:
$ ltrace -e regcomp aptitude search ZZZ
[...]
libapt-pkg.so.6.0->regcomp(0x55d9a6f1ad60, "^linux-image-[a-z0-9]*-[a-z0-9]*"..., <0-1,3>) = 0
libapt-pkg.so.6.0->regcomp(0x55d9a6f2f060, "^linux-.*-6\\.6\\.15-amd64$|^linux"..., <0-1,3>) = 0
aptitude->regcomp(0x55d9a6f1cb10, "linux-image-.*", <0-1>) = 0
aptitude->regcomp(0x55d9a6f62980, "linux-image-.*", <0-1,3>) = 0
libapt-pkg.so.6.0->regcomp(0x55d9a6ed08c0, "^linux-.*-.*$|^kfreebsd-.*-.*$|^"..., <0-1,3>) = 0
aptitude->regcomp(0x55d9a6f60270, "ZZZ", <0-1>)  = 0
aptitude->regcomp(0x55d9a6f5e830, "ZZZ", <0-1,3>) = 0
p  elpa-zzz-to-char - fancy version of `zap-to-char' command
p  python3-zzzeeksphinx - Zzzeek's Sphinx layout and utilities

(with flags here shown as bit vector with 0 being REG_EXTENDED and 1 REG_ICASE)
See how aptitude also invokes regcomp() indirectly in some apt libraries where our turning off REG_ICASE could cause problems.
Also make sure you don't use that for anything other than search in aptitude. In particular, as that $LD_PRELOAD variable will be passed along to all commands it executes, you won't want to install any package in an aptitude started in such an environment. In that regard, preloading that shared object file with /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --preload "$PWD/case-sensitive.so" /usr/bin/aptitude search... instead would be preferable as it would ensure it's only preloaded for aptitude.
GNU ed also uses the libc's POSIX regex API:
$ echo /Debian/I | ltrace -e regcomp ed -sE /etc/issue
ed->regcomp(0x5653bd71f520, "Debian", <0-1>)     = 0
Debian GNU/Linux trixie/sid \n \l
+++ exited (status 0) +++

$ echo /Debian/I | LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/case-sensitive.so ed -sE /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux trixie/sid \n \l
$ echo /debian/I | LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/case-sensitive.so ed -sE /etc/issue
?


Standard EREs don't have operators to toggle case insensitivity on or off, but perl regexps do with (?i) (?-i), so do PCRE2 ones which is a library intended to bring perl regexps to other tools. And perl regexps are mostly compatible with EREs.
And PCRE2 does happen to have support for a regcomp()/regexec() standard API in its libpcre-posix library.
That makes it relatively easy to modify aptitude to use PCRE2 instead of standard EREs.
For instance, as a PoC, all I had to do was:
$ sudo apt build-dep aptitude
$ apt source aptitude
$ cd aptitude*(/)

Create a src/regex.h as:
$ cat src/regex.h
#ifndef _REGEX_H
#define _REGEX_H 1
#include <pcre2posix.h>
#endif

Then build with:
dpkg-buildpackage -b -j5

Which failed because of the missing -lpcre2-posix. And all I had to do was:
make -C build MAYBE_LIBGTK=-lpcre2-posix

(here using the otherwise unset MAYBE_LIBGTK make variable referenced at the linking stage to avoid having to modify any file).
Then I now have an aptitude using PCRE2 regexps:
$ build/src/aptitude search -F %p '~n "^zsh$" ~d "Zsh .* unix"'
zsh
zsh:i386
$ build/src/aptitude search -F %p '~n "^zsh$" ~d "(?-i)Zsh .* unix"'
$ build/src/aptitude search -F %p '~n "^zsh$" ~d "(?-i)Zsh .* UNIX"'
zsh
zsh:i386


¹ though in the case of GNU grep, what regex engine and API is used varies with the version and a number of factors, it will likely not use the regcomp()/regexec() from the system's libc, even on systems where that's the GNU libc.

That's a bit heavy for a guy like me, but if ever I decide to start tinkering with the guts of some utility, this would be my starting introduction.
I have a solution anyway using a bit of zsh code, but I'd hoped there might be an easier way.  When searching for an installed file it seems to me that case sensitivity really is a useful option, god knows why it's not provided.
Thanks Stephane, for me you are the greatest resource of them all.
